# How can one draw a background in the elastic portion of an NSScrollView?

Tags: cocoa, nsscrollview

I have a custom `NSScrollView` with elasticity turned on in both orientations. Currently I just get a black (ugly) background when I scroll/bounce into this elastic section. How do I control what gets drawn into this section?

For a start, I would just want to be able to set the background colour of this section to a specific colour.

Things I have tried that do *NOT* seem to work:

1. Using the background property of the NSSCrollView - it doesn't seem to do anything which is also strange?
2. Setting the custom `NSScrollView.wantsLayer = true` and then choosing an appropriate `CGColor` => also no effect
3. Adding an independent subView with a background color to `NSScrollView` that fills it vertically and horizontally (even tried overfilling by using negative leading spaces) => no effect
4. Trying to use constraints to make the contentView bigger than the NSScrollView => no discernible effect
5. Making the documentView bigger => it just made the documentView extend for said amount (this was silly, but one does get desperate!)
6. Setting the background on the `NSClipView` as suggested in a comment below => no effect

Comment: I've not used it extensively, but ``NSClipView`` has a ``backgroundColor`` attribute. I think this might play some role in determining the color in the elastic portions of the scroll view. To find out for sure, you could set it via the *User Defined Runtime Attributes* panel in the *Identity Inspector* (so no need to subclass)

Comment: @PaulPatterson thanks but it didn't have any effect either. I already have the a custom `NSSCrollView` and custom `NSClipView` (to flip the grid) so it was easy enough to just set the background colour to a noticeable NSColor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if at first you don't succeed (and nobody has answered your question on SO yet)...

What worked is to add a subview to the NSClipView (not the NSScrollView) constraining it to be adjacent to the documentView where the elasticity is arising. That's all...

Answer (score 2):

Add a subview to the scrollView which is not the documentView, and this view will not scroll or magnify.  Constrain that view to the edges so that it is the full size of the scrollView

Comment: @JustSid thanks I totally missed that! allow me an edit and kindly reconsider your downvote. Happy new year

Comment: Reversed my vote and deleted the original comment. Happy new year to you too! :)

Comment: @Jef I tried that and it didn't work. I even tried constraining it outside the bounds of the NSScrollView using a negative leading width & height. Is that something that you have working in practise or just a theory? (Happy New Year :-)

Answer (score 0):

This answer applies if you have a custom `NSView` assigned as your `documentView`.

As of the macOS 14 SDK, assuming you haven't overridden `clipsToBounds` (which now defaults to `NO`), `drawRect` will be called with a dirty rectangle that may exceed the bounds of the view, which allows you to draw the overhang that appears during elastic scrolling.

In prior versions of the SDK, it is necessary to instead define a `drawBackgroundOverhangInRect` method in your `NSView` subclass to do this drawing instead. In this case, `clipsToBounds` must be kept at the default value of `YES`, or this method will not be called (in my experience).